# Jsoup getElementsByAttributeValueMatching doesn't function

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I have an html page that has (among others) the following Divs:

```
<div id="fact">
    <div class="fact">
       AAAAAA
     <div class="fact-label">
         BBBBBB
     </div> 
    </div>
 </div>
```

I want to extract only the text of div which has class="fact"

Code:

```
Document page = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements element = page.select("div.fact"); 
        for (Element step : element) {

 System.out.println(step.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching("class", 
 Pattern.compile("^[a-t]{4}$")));
}
```

but it does'nt work ,what I get is this:

```
<div class="fact">
    AAAAAA
   <div class="fact-label">
    BBBBBB
    </div> 
</div>
```

My question is : how can I exclude the inner Div which has class="fact-label" ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen He is using a parser.

Comment: @revo Forgive my knee jerk reaction (which, sadly, is usually right).

Comment: I am using latest version which is 1.11.3

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I am getting same result as you showed in question, but that is *proper* result for that code since it is asking for elements with `class` attribute has 4 letters and `<div class="fact">`(along with its content, which includes descendent elements) matches that criteria. Can you explain logic which you are using to decide which elements should be removed or more importantly *how* they should be removed? For instance if `<div class="fact-label">` contains `<div class="abcd">` should that `<div class="abcd">` be removed along with `<div class="fact-label">`?

Comment: 1 - o.k. you are right, when I look at the Jsoup API for getElementsByAttributeValueMatching method it says:
"Find elements that have attributes whose values match the supplied regular expression and returns elements that have attributes matching this regular expression" but it does not say (along with its  descendent elements)
 2 -  <div class="fact-label"> will not contain any div I want to remove it.

Comment: I am not keen on using regex, any suggestion to remove <div class="fact-label"> would be appreciated

Comment: I am sure what you *really* want to do, but if you want to remove all `<div class="fact-label">` which are inside `<div class="fact">` then all you need is `page.select("div.fact div.fact-label").remove();`. But if your goal is more general (like you shown in your example which was based on length of `class` attribute) you can try with selector like `element[attribute~=regex]`. So maybe you want something like `page.select("div[class~=^.{4}$] div[class~=^.{5,}$]").remove();` to remove all divs with class length of 5 or more, which are inside divs which class length is exactly 4 characters.

Comment: About "but it does not say (along with its descendent elements)": it is because it doesn't select descendent elements. Only *selected* element was `<div class="fact">` but printing it involves traversing over all *other* elements it "holds/wraps".

Comment: Is your expected output `AAAAAA`? Then use `Jsoup.parse(html).selectFirst("div.fact").ownText()`. If your expected result is  `<div class="fact">
  AAAAAA  
</div>` use this remove all children elements:
  `Element element = Jsoup.parse(html).select("div.fact").get(0);
  element.select("* > *").remove();
  System.out.println(element.outerHtml());`

Comment: thank you guys but the following code solved my problem:
         System.out.println(step.select("div").remove().select("div.fact").text());

Comment: In that case maybe you are looking for (which IMO is more readable) `System.out.println(page.select("div.fact").first().ownText())` or if there can be more elements like `div.fact` use loop `for (Element fact : page.select("div.fact")){ System.out.println(fact.ownText();) }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solved the problem:

```
elem.select("div").remove().select("div.fact").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the following code to get the result, here we are asking the regex to match the word ending with "fact" (using $ to denote end of the string) and then extracting the "owntext()". owntext() will return only the text from this element only, it will not include texts from its children.

Elements el = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching("class", "fact$");

```
    for (Element ele : el){
        System.out.println(ele.ownText());
    }
```

Output:
AAAAAA